# ReactJS app authentication and authorization with Azure AD with OpenID connect

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-graph-api

I wanted to implement ReactJS application authentication with Azure AD with OpenID connect. Microsoft has provided MSAL2.0 library (MSAL React supports the authorization code flow) but is it based on OpenID connect protocol?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSAL Standards compliant with OAuth v2.0 and OpenID Connect (OIDC).

When it comes to your scenario MSAL React uses the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange), providing additional security.

You can find more information here [MSAL for React](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/msal-for-react-is-here/#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20the%20MSAL%20React%20library%20works%20with,Code%20Flow%20with%20PKCE.%20-Microsoft%20identity%20platform%20team)